# Javascript : Phaser call a method inside another method class

Tags: javascript, class, methods, phaser-framework

I am facing a problem during my development in javascript with Phaser. I try to call a method inside a method of a class but I have an error.

Here is my class :

```
import Enemy from '../classes/Enemy';
import Turret from '../classes/Turret';
import Bullet from '../classes/Bullet';


class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene {

    constructor() {
        super({
            key: 'GameScene'
        });
    }

    preload()
    {
        this.load.image('turret', './www/assets/tour_simple.png');
    }

    drawGrid(graphics)
    {
        graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x0000ff, 0.8);
        for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            graphics.moveTo(0, i * 64);
            graphics.lineTo(640, i * 64);
        }
        for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            graphics.moveTo(j * 64, 0);
            graphics.lineTo(j * 64, 512);
        }
        graphics.strokePath();
    }

    canPlaceTurret(i, j)
    {
        return this.map[i][j] === 0;
    }

    placeTurret(pointer)
    {
        var i = Math.floor(pointer.y/64);
        var j = Math.floor(pointer.x/64);
        if(this.canPlaceTurret(i, j)) {
            var turret = this.turrets.get();
            if (turret)
            {
                turret.setActive(true);
                turret.setVisible(true);
                turret.place(i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    damageEnemy(enemy, bullet)
    {
        // only if both enemy and bullet are alive
        if (enemy.active === true && bullet.active === true) {
            // we remove the bullet right away
            bullet.setActive(false);
            bullet.setVisible(false);

            //todo mettre dans une classe constante
            var BULLET_DAMAGE = 25;
            // decrease the enemy hp with BULLET_DAMAGE
            enemy.receiveDamage(BULLET_DAMAGE);
        }
    }



    create() {
        this.add.text(200, 230, 'good!', { fill: '#0f0' });

        var graphics = this.add.graphics();

        this.map = [[ 0,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [ 0,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [ 0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, 0, 0],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0]];

        //TODO creer une classe qui dessine le path
        // the path for our enemies
        // parameters are the start x and y of our path
        this.path = this.add.path(96, -32);
        this.path.lineTo(96, 164);
        this.path.lineTo(480, 164);
        this.path.lineTo(480, 544);

        graphics.lineStyle(3, 0xffffff, 1);
        // visualize the path
        this.path.draw(graphics);

        this.enemies = this.physics.add.group({ classType: Enemy, runChildUpdate: true });

        this.nextEnemy = 0;

        var graphics = this.add.graphics();
        this.drawGrid(graphics);

        this.turrets = this.add.group({ classType: Turret, runChildUpdate: true });
        this.input.on('pointerdown', this.placeTurret);

        this.bullets = this.physics.add.group({ classType: Bullet, runChildUpdate: true });

        this.physics.add.overlap(this.enemies, this.bullets, this.damageEnemy);
    }

    update(time, delta) {
        if (time > this.nextEnemy)
        {
            var enemy = this.enemies.get();
            console.log(enemy);
            if (enemy)
            {
                enemy.setActive(true);
                enemy.setVisible(true);
                // place the enemy at the start of the path
                enemy.startOnPath();

                this.nextEnemy = time + 2000;
            }
        }
    }


}

export default GameScene;
```

And an error occurs during my game :

> TypeError: this.canPlaceTurret is not a function

The error is from the `placeTurret` method where I call the `canPlaceTurret` method.

I have tried some things like adding an attribute to my class : `self = this;` and call my function with `self.canPlaceTurret` but there is always the problem. I think it is a scope problem but I don't know how to solve that.

**Another important information : we are using Webpack**

Thanks for reading :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
this.input.on('pointerdown', this.placeTurret);
```

with:

```
this.input.on('pointerdown', pointer => this.placeTurret(pointer));
```

*(slighthy edited following your comment below)*

Basically, when you pass your method as a callback, it becomes a simple function reference. When that function is called later, `this` won't refer to the class instance you're expecting, because it's no longer called in the context of your class.

By using the fat arrow syntax, you create a specific callback instead, and explicitly tells it to call the method in the context of the current (as in, at the time said callback is defined) `this`.

Alternatively, you can also do:

```
this.input.on('pointerdown', this.placeTurret.bind(this));
```

Instead of creating a new anonymous function, this takes your method as a reference (like it was doing to begin with) but manually binds the current `this` to it.

Please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/965834) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Yes it was that ! Thank you very much.

Just I have replace with that :

`this.input.on('pointerdown', (pointer) => this.placeTurret(pointer));`

Because I need the pointer object for the function :)

Comment: Like the answer mentions, this binds up a new function reference, which needs more memory for something unnecessary. You need to bind the scope of the function so that "this" isn't the event: `this.input.on('pointerdown', this.placeTurret.bind(this));` would be the more performant solution I believe. Please let me know if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Won't it work without using the **this** keyword at all in your placeTurret() method when calling the canPlaceTurret()?

```
 placeTurret(pointer)
        {
            var i = Math.floor(pointer.y/64);
            var j = Math.floor(pointer.x/64);
            if(canPlaceTurret(i, j)) {
                var turret = this.turrets.get();
                if (turret)
                {
                    turret.setActive(true);
                    turret.setVisible(true);
                    turret.place(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
```